# Como insertar datos en una tabla evitando duplicados

Tags: php, mysql, csv

espero alguien me pueda dar una idea.

Estoy intentando subir datos con valores únicos verificando la "referencia", pero puede hacer una excepción siempre y cuando la fecha sea diferente

En el siguiente ejemplo de datos, la primera linea debe subir, la segunda no y la tercera si:

[image: Datos de carga csv]

```
$checkDuplicateSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM santander WHERE referencia = '$referencia'AND fecha = '$fecha'";
            $duplicateResult = $conn->query($checkDuplicateSQL);
            $duplicateCount = $duplicateResult->fetch_assoc()['count'];
            
            if ($duplicateCount > 0) {
                $registrosDuplicados++;
                continue; // Saltar al siguiente registro
            }
            
            // Sentencia SQL para insertar en la tabla "santander"
            $sql = "INSERT INTO santander (fecha, hora, sucursal, concepto, retiro, deposito, saldo, referencia) VALUES ('$fecha', '$hora', '$sucursal', '$concepto', '$retiro', '$deposito', '$saldo', '$referencia')";
```

El asunto es que si se estan subiendo los duplicados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese `continue` me da muy mal rollo, ¿por qué no metes el `INSERT` dentro de un `if($duplicateCount==0)` que tendrá el mismo efecto? Y utiliza consultas preparadas, por Diossss :) ¿Puede ser que ese dato duplicado estuviera de antes? ¿Cómo estás depurando ese código? Evita las imágenes, inserta en modo texto

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tus comentarios, soy nuevo en esto, así que tomaré tus comentarios muy a detalle para hacer las correcciones y esperar a que funcione!!